# SHA512 hashes differ on android, php and javascript

Tags: php, android, hash, sha512, cryptojs

I am using the SHA512 hash to transfer some encrypted data between my app and it's backend. However, I'm having a odd situation and have no idea what might be causing it.

So, I've got following setups tested:

Android 2x SHA512

Android 1x SHA512 -> CryptoJS 1x SHA512

PHP 2x SHA512

So, when I do the first 2x Android hashing, I get the same result as when I do the 1x android -> 1x cryptojs.
However, when I do the PHP 2x, I get the same result as I get on the first Android pass, but the second encryption pass of the PHP is different.

On PHP, I've tried both the hash() and openssl_digest() functions with raw bytes as output.

PHP:

```
$firstpass = base64_encode(hash('sha512', $enteredPassword, true));
//$firstpass = base64_encode(hash('sha512', $enteredPassword, true));

//$secondpass = base64_encode(openssl_digest($firstpass, 'sha512', true));
$secondpass = base64_encode(hash('sha512', $firstpass, true));
```

Android:

```
public static String encryptPassword(String password) {
    MessageDigest md = null;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (md != null) {
        md.update(password.getBytes());
        byte byteData[] = md.digest();
        String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(byteData, Base64.DEFAULT);

        return base64;
    }
    return password;
}
```

CryptoJS:

```
var password = cryptojs.SHA512(req.params.password);
var basepassword = password.toString(cryptojs.enc.Base64);
```

Why would my first hash be correct and my second not and how could I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SHA1 is not made for security, don't use it for this.
Grab any implementation of BCrypt and do security right.
As for the different hashes: Most likely an encoding issue related to Strings.

Comment: I'm just trying to find out why I can't get these to match, but I'll check out BCrypt as well. I found out that the 2x Android and Android->CryptoJS had a newline in the base64 string, but the PHP version did not have any newlines in the base64 :S

Comment: Then i was not too far off with encoding ;)

Comment: Yeah, but I still have no clue why the PHP doesn't have the newline chars :(

Comment: BASE64 encoding sometimes produces a defined length of line and enters a newline. this can be turned off for every library. In your case: `Base64.encodeToString(byteData, Base64.NO_WRAP)`

Comment: Damn, that was the solution!!! I set the Base64.DEFAULT to Base64.NO_WRAP on Android and it was solved! Thanks a bunch!