# Hash symfony2 password in Javascript

Tags: javascript, symfony, sha512

I wouldlike to hashing a password like symfony2, but in javascript. This is my code in Javascript :

```
this.hashPassword = function(salt, clearPassword) {

    var digest = "";
    console.log('==== STARTING HASHING PASSWORD ====');
    var salted = null;
    if (!salt || salt == "") {
      salted = clearPassword;
    } else {
      salted = clearPassword + "{" + salt + "}";
    }

    digest = CryptoJS.SHA512(salted);
    for (var i=1; i<5000; i++) {
      digest = CryptoJS.SHA512(digest.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1)+salted);
    }
    digest = digest.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
    console.log('==== ENDING HASHING PASSWORD ====');
    console.log(digest);
    return digest;
};
```

The hash password i obtain isn't the same in the database, i don't really know why. My password in Symfony2 is hashed in SHA512 with a salt, i'm sure, because i test a code in PHP and it works.

Can you help me please ?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need to hash your password in JS ? It's not safe because the salt is readable by anybody with this method.

Comment: ^Yeah agreed, stupidest thing of this week.

Comment: Because i'm on an app developed in javascript. and i wouldlike to communicate with a backend developed in symfony2. So, sorry if my idea is stupid for you, i just want a solution about that, not a lynch. Thank you

Comment: @FlorentGuenebeaud so what if you send the password as-is?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23149654/5191221) is

```
SHA1 [..] not made for security [..] grab any implementation of BCrypt
```

but there is an explanation that maybe a line break causes the different hashes. This can be turned off with `Base64.encodeToString(byteData, Base64.NO_WRAP)` in their case.